# Winning meal by betting is halal or haram

Tags: halal-haram

My question is that my two friends betting on something, loser will pay all expenses of the meal, I want to know is this meal is haram for me or not, and if it is haram and I pay my payment for meal but eat together then still is it haram?

Comment: betting is haram in islam, and the money which will come by betting that will also be haram, so stay away from this and also keep your friends away from this.

Answer (score -2):

I think, If losers intention **treat to** meal there is no problem. But if somebody is always going to be a loser, and if his intention changes, maybe its haram.